# C# copy and paste datagridview to Powerpoint slide with formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview, interop, powerpoint

Is there a way to copy entire datagridview object to powerpoint slide keeping foratting? I've tried the following code but its give me `Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted` error

```
        PP.Application ppt = new PP.Application();
        PP.Presentation pres = ppt.Presentations.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        PP.Slides slides = pres.Slides;
        PP.Slide slide = slides.AddSlide(1,pres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[PP.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText]);

        datagridview1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
        datagridview1.SelectAll();
        DataObject obj = datagridview1.GetClipboardContent();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(obj, true);

        PP.ShapeRange sr = slide.Shapes.Paste();//Error on this line
```

If there is a way to export the dataGridView as an image, its fine as well. The final user doesn't have to interact with the data. I have tried adding datagridview to picture box, but I couldn't figure out how to bind them together. Thanks,

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745532.aspx

Comment: as far I know you need to select the slide to paste the content slide.Select();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have your grid content rendered to an image - check [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403831/how-to-create-an-image-of-a-wpf-usercontrol-at-runtime) or google for "render wpf control to image". Don't forget to use proper clipboard format id, or use Clipboard.SetImage instead of SetDataObject.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I finally got it working. Since I'm working with Winforms I used `.DrawToBitmap()` Method and its working.