# WPF Ensure RenderTargetBitmap has updated Binding values from background thread changes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, rendertargetbitmap

I'm having a problem with RenderTargetBitmap, in that I can't get it consistently grab an updated render after I change bound properties on a background thread.

Here is what I have:

```
        // Update a property on an INotifyPropertyChanged view model
        // This runs on a background thread
        viewModel.SomeBoundProperty += 10;

        // Flush dispatcher queue (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596035/612510)
        _lcd.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {}, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);

        // Render the updated control
        _lcd.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            _lcd.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(240, 160));
            _lcd.Arrange(new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, 240, 160));
            _lcd.UpdateLayout();

            _renderTarget.Render(_lcd);
        }
```

Alas, approximately half the time I'm getting the render before the control is updated with the new value, and the other half it updates correctly.

From what I understand WPF dispatches property change notifications automatically to the UI thread. How can I ensure that these dispatched notifications are all processed before doing the render? This code works fine if I make sure `SomeBoundProperty` is updated on the Dispatcher thread, but that is less than ideal for this particular application.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some trial and error has me figuring that property change notifications are dispatched at the `DispatcherPriority.Background` priority, so changing the flushing line to this:

```
// Flush dispatcher queue 
_lcd.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {}, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

...looks like it fixed the problem. `DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle` is one level below `DispatcherPriority.Backgound`. The render now updates consistently every time.