# ContentControl + RenderTargetBitmap + empty image

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol, rendertargetbitmap

Im trying to create some chart images without ever displaying those charts on the screen. I'v been at this for quite a while and tried a lot of different things but nothing seems to work. The code works perfectly if I display the chart in a window first, but if I don't display it in a window, the bitmap is just white with a black border (no idea why).

I have tried adding the chart to a border before rendering and giving the border a green borderBrush. In the bitmap, I see the green borderBrush then the black border and white background but no chart. The Chart is not contained in a black boarder so I don't know where that is coming from.

I have tried adding the chart to a window without calling window.Show() and again I just get the black boarder and white background. However if I call window.Show() the bitmap contains the chart.

I have tried using a drawingVisual as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2009/07/03/rendertargetbitmap-tips.aspx), same result.

Here is the code (not including adding the element to a border or window):

```
private static BitmapSource CreateElementScreenshot(FrameworkElement element, int dpi)
{
    if (!element.IsMeasureValid)
    {
        Size size = new Size(element.Width, element.Height);
        element.Measure(size);
        element.Arrange(new Rect(size));
    }

    element.UpdateLayout();

    var scale = dpi/96.0;

    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap
        (
            (int)(scale * element.RenderSize.Width),(int)(scale * element.RenderSize.Height),dpi,dpi,PixelFormats.Default
        );

    // this is waiting for dispatcher to perform measure, arrange and render passes
    element.Dispatcher.Invoke(((Action)(() => renderTargetBitmap.Render(element))), DispatcherPriority.Render);

    return renderTargetBitmap;
}
```

Note: The chart is a ContentControl.

Is there anyway I can get the chart to render without displaying it in a window first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling element.ApplyTemplate() did the trick.

Comment: It's not working for me. Where did you insert in your code the ApplyTemplate?

Comment: Sorry it's been two years since I answered this and I don't have access to that code anymore. Try adding it before the UpdateLayout

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. You saved me a lot of trouble! :)

Answer (score 2):

If someone has similar problems with rendering **RenderTargetBitmap** (getting **white / empty image**) items that are in StackPanel you can temporary move them to **Grid**, then render and put it back in **StackPanel**

```
Grid grid = new System.Windows.Controls.Grid() { Background = Brushes.White, Width = iWidth, Height = iHeight };
Panel panel = plot.Parent as Panel;

if (panel != null)
{
    panel.Children.Remove(plot);
    grid.Children.Add(plot);

    grid.Measure(new Size(iWidth, iHeight));
    grid.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(iWidth, iHeight)));
}
plot.Measure(new Size(iWidth, iHeight));
plot.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(iWidth, iHeight)));

plot.ApplyTemplate();
plot.UpdateLayout();

grid.ApplyTemplate();
grid.UpdateLayout();

RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    iWidth,
    iHeight,
    96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
renderTargetBitmap.Render(grid);

PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
encoder.Save(memoryStream);
bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(memoryStream);

if (panel != null)
{
    grid.Children.Remove(plot);
    panel.Children.Add(plot);
}

plot.Measure(new Size(iWidthBefore, iHeightBefore));
plot.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(iWidthBefore, iHeightBefore)));
plot.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found a blog post about this as well as I have documented in another SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522380/get-a-bitmap-image-from-a-control-view/28626055#28626055

Answer (score 2):

For me, calling element.Arrange() was the missing piece.