# Accessing PrintPageEventArgs.PageVisual in Winform or its equivalent

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2012, printing

I would like to print the visual contents of a WPF control (a MapControl) that I added to my Winform application.

(Basically, compile a WPF User Control with whatever control and then add the resultant control like any other control to your Winform project.)

Another user basically gave some code to accomplish the printing part. See:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q386207

The code that I could gather in the Winform side should be:

```
private PrintDocument m_oPrintDoc;
public frmWhatever()
    : base()
{
    // This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set up the printing
    m_oPrintDoc = new PrintDocument();
    m_oPrintDoc.PrintPage += PrintDoc_PrintPage;
}

void PrintDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.PageVisual = MapContainer;
}
```

The problem is that PageVisual does not exist on the Winform side. It obviously does in WPF.

What would be the equivalent code? I have no problem with the "MapContainer" part. The only missing ingredient is the "e.what" method?

Is it possible that PageVisual exists if I add a reference / using pair?

Before anyone asks me to contact DevExpress, I already tried that. Their response was that the question has nothing whatsoever to do with them and is a pure Microsoft.Net question, hence the question here.

Oh yes, I am using Visual Studio 2012 with .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. The first function got placed in the WPF control. I had to build once. I then obtained the image in the print callback, which I used to set the image.

```
public System.Drawing.Image GetMapImage()
{
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)this.mapControl1.ActualWidth, (int)this.mapControl1.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    rtb.Render(this.mapControl1);
    PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
    MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    png.Save(stream);
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

    return image;
}

void PrintDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current map image. do not continue, if no image.
    Image oMapResized = ((bvMaps.MapDevex)this.mapMain.Child).GetMapImage();
    if (null == oMapResized)
        return;

    // Draw the image on the paper starting at the upper left corner.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)oMapResized, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

I found another post here on StackOverflow, which got me to the answer. The code works for any WPF control.

[Get a bitmap image from a Control view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522380/get-a-bitmap-image-from-a-control-view)

I did have to add some references on both sides (Winforms and WPF), but at the end of the day, success!

Answer (score 1):

You're printing in WinForms using GDI.

Your code should look like (untested):

```
void PrintDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(e.MarginBounds);
    MapContainer.DrawToBitmap(bmp, e.MarginBounds);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

When this shows something you'll have to tune the scaling. Can be a lot of fun (not), use PrintPreviewDialog to save some paper.

Comment: The above answer did not work. There is no DrawToBitmap(). I did manage to implement a sort of workaround to get the above code, but that just gave trash as an output. The answer, did, however, put me on the right path. I will create another answer with the actual code that resolves the issue and post on DevExpress as well.

Comment: DrawBitmap is a GDI function, the ElementHost should have it. But your own answer probably yields a better bitmap.