# How to save a WPF chart toolkit as image in the clipboard?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpftoolkit

I already was using Windows form chart and I was able to save the chart control in the clipboard with these codes:

```
    Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    SummaryChart.SaveImage(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    Dim bmp As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream)
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp)
```

But since the requirements have changed then I had to create the chart in the view with the use of WPF Chart toolkit :

```
xmlns:dv="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

SummaryChart.SaveImage does not work anymore.
What is the best way of doing what I was doing before?

I have read this article: [Get a bitmap image from a Control view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522380/get-a-bitmap-image-from-a-control-view)   and tried these codes:

```
 Dim rtb = New RenderTargetBitmap(CInt(SummariesChart.ActualWidth), 
 CInt(SummariesChart.ActualHeight), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
 rtb.Render(SummariesChart)
 Dim png  = New PngBitmapEncoder()
 png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb))
 Dim stream  = New MemoryStream()
 png.Save(stream)
 Clipboard.SetImage(rtb)
```

But still, it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To save WPF Chart toolkit image as like below code. Add the BitMapFrame in Encoder.Frames and then save the image.

```
Public Shared Sub SaveAsImage(ByVal element As FrameworkElement, ByVal filepath As String, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer)
element.Width = width
element.Height = height
element.Measure(New Size(width, height))
element.Arrange(New Rect(0, 0, width, height))
element.UpdateLayout()
Dim target = New RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
target.Render(element)
Dim encoder = New PngBitmapEncoder()
Dim outputFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(target)
encoder.Frames.Add(outputFrame)

Using file = File.OpenWrite(filepath)
    encoder.Save(file)
End Using End Sub
```

Comment: I have used encoder eg   Dim png  = New PngBitmapEncoder().
Also, I do not pass the filepath. I want to save it in the clipboard.
Do you have any idea that how do I do that?

Comment: See my code above. Use system.drawing.image to copy that into the stream and then use clipboard to send it to it.